# App ready for sale doesn't load map tiles from google maps sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am using Google Maps SDK for iOS. The app is working fine when installed with testflight. The problem is that the app once it arrived in App Store stopped loading the map's tiles. 
What could be the problem?

Comment: may be your google app key expire?

Comment: no, it's still working when I install my app from xcode

Comment: have you checked ios versions?